# Ruby Weighted Round Robin

Tags: ruby

I have an unknown number of things, let's say 100 apples that all have the same mass.

I have two buckets with total weights I'm trying to hit when all the apples are in the buckets - Bucket 1 with 60% of the total weight, and Bucket 2 with 40%.

I need a simple ruby algorithm to put the apples one by one into the buckets. I need to keep the two buckets as equally distributed as possible while I'm filling them up.

I will not be able to do this all at once, so I won't know which was the last apple to go into the last bucket. But I can always know the total number of apples in each bucket.

(This is a real problem I'm trying to solve, not a homework question - I'm just phrasing it this way so it will be easy to understand.)

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on `keep the two buckets as equally distributed as possible`? I am assuming you want 60% of apples go to Bucket 1, but that would be proportionally rather than equally?

Comment: Can you just put an apple into a bucket that has the least apples in it?

Comment: Might be worth checking out ruby workers?

Comment: Added a new answer borrowing some ideas from @SteveTurczyn, as such it's marked as a community wiki. Anyhow this new answer is more robust, more readable and wrapped up in a method. I'd prefer if you unnaccept the currently accepted answer so I can delete it (it has limitations such as only being able to take weightings from higher to lower). I don't mind about the rep loss, it's more important this question has a more correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for that Justin. I've made a slight modification to the code which corrects a little bug for step 1. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a method to add items to two variables, according to the weighted rules supplied to the parameters:

```
def fill_with_ratio(weighting1, weighting2, items)

  b1 = 0
  b2 = 0
  ratio = weighting1.fdiv weighting2
  steps = []

  #step 1 empty buckets
  if b1 + b2 == 0
    if ratio <= 1.0
      b2 += 1
    else
      b1 += 1
    end
  end

  steps << { step: 1, b1: b1, b2: b2, ratio: b1.fdiv(b2).round(2) }

  #steps 2 to items
  (items-1).times.with_index(2) do |_,i|

    r1 = b1.succ.fdiv b2
    r2 = b1.fdiv b2.succ

    if (r1 - ratio).abs <= (r2 - ratio).abs
      b1 += 1
    else
      b2 += 1
    end

    steps << { step: i, b1: b1, b2: b2, ratio: b1.fdiv(b2).round(2) }

  end
  steps
end
```

The `if` expressions decide which variables to increment by one in order to achieve the closest match to the defined distribution. The `steps` array only serves to show the steps after each addition. It can be omitted with no effect.

---

**Key methods:** [`Integer#fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv), [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-times), [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), [`Integer#succ`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-succ) and [`Integer#abs`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-abs).

---

#### Example One:

```
require 'pp' #pp prints everything nicely.

pp fill_with_ratio(60, 40, 100)
#[{:step=>1, :b1=>1, :b2=>0, :ratio=>0.0},
# {:step=>2, :b1=>1, :b2=>1, :ratio=>1.0},
# {:step=>3, :b1=>2, :b2=>1, :ratio=>2.0},
# {:step=>4, :b1=>2, :b2=>2, :ratio=>1.0},
# {:step=>5, :b1=>3, :b2=>2, :ratio=>1.5},
# .
# .
# .
# {:step=>98, :b1=>59, :b2=>39, :ratio=>1.51},
# {:step=>99, :b1=>59, :b2=>40, :ratio=>1.48},
# {:step=>100, :b1=>60, :b2=>40, :ratio=>1.5}]
```

#### Example Two:

```
pp fill_with_ratio(30, 40, 21)
#[{:step=>1, :b1=>0, :b2=>1, :ratio=>Infinity},
# {:step=>2, :b1=>1, :b2=>1, :ratio=>1.0},
# {:step=>3, :b1=>1, :b2=>2, :ratio=>0.5},
# {:step=>4, :b1=>2, :b2=>2, :ratio=>1.0},
# {:step=>5, :b1=>2, :b2=>3, :ratio=>0.67},
# {:step=>6, :b1=>3, :b2=>3, :ratio=>1.0},
# {:step=>7, :b1=>3, :b2=>4, :ratio=>0.75},
# {:step=>8, :b1=>3, :b2=>5, :ratio=>0.6},
# {:step=>9, :b1=>4, :b2=>5, :ratio=>0.8},
# {:step=>10, :b1=>4, :b2=>6, :ratio=>0.67},
# {:step=>11, :b1=>5, :b2=>6, :ratio=>0.83},
# {:step=>12, :b1=>5, :b2=>7, :ratio=>0.71},
# {:step=>13, :b1=>6, :b2=>7, :ratio=>0.86},
# {:step=>14, :b1=>6, :b2=>8, :ratio=>0.75},
# {:step=>15, :b1=>6, :b2=>9, :ratio=>0.67},
# {:step=>16, :b1=>7, :b2=>9, :ratio=>0.78},
# {:step=>17, :b1=>7, :b2=>10, :ratio=>0.7},
# {:step=>18, :b1=>8, :b2=>10, :ratio=>0.8},
# {:step=>19, :b1=>8, :b2=>11, :ratio=>0.73},
# {:step=>20, :b1=>9, :b2=>11, :ratio=>0.82},
# {:step=>21, :b1=>9, :b2=>12, :ratio=>0.75}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bucket_1, bucket_2 = add_apple(bucket_1, bucket_2, percentage_ratio)

def add_apple(bucket_1, bucket_2, percentage_ratio)

  if bucket_1 + bucket_2 == 0
    if percentage_ratio >= 50.0
      bucket_1 += 1
    else
      bucket_2 += 1
    end
    return bucket_1, bucket_2
  end

  if bucket_1.to_f * 100 / (bucket_1 + bucket_2) < percentage_ratio
    bucket_1 += 1
  else
    bucket_2 += 1
  end
  return bucket_1, bucket_2
end
```